# Is there a process for petitioning Google to factor accessibility into search results ranking?

Tags: seo, google, accessibility

As the questions says, is there a process for petitioning Google to factor accessibility into search results ranking?

I know individual accounts can submit feature requests to specific Google products, but I was wondering if there's a more formal process, even an enterprise-level one.

Comment: Google is notoriously insular, and their search algorithm is kept close to their chest. I wouldn't be surprised if the "enterprise-level" process is to have one of your engineers go out for coffee with one of their friends who works at Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **not** a process for *any* 3rd party to petition that Google make *anything* a rankings factor. Determining what *is* and what *is not* a rankings factor is private to Google.

Keep in mind that there are over 200 ranking *signals*, very few of which do SEOs actually know about.

Sometimes when website owners are very slow to implement "good" practices, Google encourages their adoption with a slight rankings boost. This is typically in the form of a "tie breaker" - if two sites are competing for a position on a SERP, then the one that is compliant with the "good" practice will get the spot. We've seen this recently with the Page Experience update, and also the "Mobile first" update a few years ago.

There have been many discussions about accessibility becoming a rankings factor in the past. When asked if it would ever become a thing (on Twitter), Google's John Mueller has said:

> I won't say never, but I'm not aware of any immediate plans. In general though, when sites are hard to use, people steer away from them anyway, so over time things like recommendations & other signals tend to drop away, resulting in the site being less visible in search too.

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-accessibility-ranking-factor-29273.html

Comment: Cheers, @Mike Ciffone